# How to use the same clean() method in two different forms in django?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have two forms `NewItem(ModelForm)` and `EditItem(ModelForm)`. I overrode the `clean()` method of `NewItem(ModelForm)` to validate the fields. I would like to re-use the same `clean()` method in `EditItem(ModelForm)` incase the use tries to edit and re-save the data? Is there a clean way to achieve this without copy and paste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use inheritance for that:

- make `EditItem` inherit from `NewItem`: `EditItem(NewItem)`
- or both forms inherit from a class that defines only the `clean()` method, for example `CleanItemForm(ModelForm)`, and then you define`NewItem(CleanItemForm)` and `EditItem(CleanItemForm)`.

Note: I'm new to Django and there may be another method that I don't know about.

Comment: Went with the second approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can **create a mixin class named `FormCleanMixin()`** which will contain the `clean()` method common between the 2 forms. Then inherit this mixin class in your 2 forms.

First, create the mixin class like:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class FormCleanMixin(ModelForm):

    def clean(self):
        ...
        # your common code for 'clean()' here
```

Now, inherit this mixin class in your two forms like:

```
class NewItem(FormCleanMixin): # inherit the mixin

    ... # your code

class EditItem(FormCleanMixin): # inherit the mixin

    ... # your code
```

Comment: You might run into a `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited.`...so might be better to inherit from `BaseForm`